# ¿Cómo hacer joins en postgresql de varias tablas?

Tags: postgresql

Necesito hacer una consulta que involucra por lo menos 4 tablas ya tengo una parte de la consulta pero necesito hacer un reporte completo, por favor si alguien tiene un ejemplo del cual basarme.

Gracias

Comment: podrías publicar parte de lo que ya has realizado

Comment: Saludos Álvaro, bienvenido a la hermandad de SOes, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas cómo funciona el sitio, aumentes la calidad a tu pregunta editándola para añadir mayores detalles y finalmente percibo que estás aprendiendo a usar PostgreSQL, este tutorial te será de utilidad: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/index.htm

Comment: Buenas tardes Paulo, así estoy empezando en postgres reviso la documentación que me sugieres realizo pruebas. Si continúo con dudas agrego mas  detalles a mi pregunta.  Michas gracias